# AdGuard Home on home lab K8s with MetalLB - Android cellphones lose connection?

Tags: routing, kubernetes, android, bare-metal

I have a K3s based Kubernetes cluster running with MetalLB as load balancer. Assigning IPs to services works like a charm. I can also access the IPs from the MetalLB IP range through a keepalived VIP and a static route in my router. Works like a charm on most devices.

I also have an AdGuard Home running in my cluster with a static IP from MetalLB's range that I can also reach from my local network. It works well for most devices too.

For most. Unfortunately, for some reason Android cellphones in my local wifi network lose DNS resolution after some time when connected to the wifi network. I disconnect and reconnect them and everything works again, only to stop again after a couple minutes. I haven't pinpointed the exact time when it fails.

What might be the issue? Why is it working on every machine except for the two Android phones that I have on the network? How can I find the cause?